# Is it safe to drink the whey?

Tags: cheese-making

If you make cheese with starter culture and rennet is the whey that is a byproduct of this process safe to drink? I have heard from some that there does exist some who are fond of drinking this but I'm not sure if the whey from rennet is safe?

Comment: If you don't want to use it as-is, you can make ricotta from it : https://www.fiascofarm.com/dairy/ricotta.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whey is an excellent source of protein and whey protein in particular is used in many body-building supplements.

Please see the excerpt below from  [FARMcurious](http://www.farmcurious.com/cheesemaking-what-to-do-with-all-that-whey/) .

> Drink Up! – The acidic tang of whey may be a bit of an acquired tasted but I actually find it refreshing.  Cultured whey has pro-biotics that can help balance the microflora in your gut as an extra bonus to the protein.

The web page gives a lot of information about whey and the many other uses for it as well as a great tip for storing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Whey is an excellent element when making soup.  I generally use it with home made stock. It adds complexity in a good way.